# 1 to 1 planetary gear

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need a 1 to 1 planetary gear box that torque increases
I was told torque in planetary gear sets are because of the number of teeth moving over the sun gear.

I was told the more spur gears with teeth means the more torque regardless of the increase .

Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it looks like you're asking for a gearbox that has an output shaft of equal speed but greater torque than the input shaft; this is not physically possible unless you have a secondary input shaft supplying power from an auxiliary power supply (and ensuring the speed of the output shaft equals the primary input shaft involves controlling the speed of the secondary input shaft, which may be impractical). Without a secondary shaft, an increase in torque without decreasing speed is a violation of power conservation. If I've misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking- are you asking about analyzing a gear, or material selection, or just something off the shelf?

Comment: I was told the reason a planetary gear has torque is because of the number of spurs. If there is 1 spur then it has x torque if it has 3 spurs it has 3 times x and so on, I was told planetary gears have toque because of spurs and not ratio,  And I can locate the same motor with the same rpm but different torque. I have a 50 rpm  7.5kg and a 90 rpm 8.8 kg. Somewhere in those motors there is a 1 to 1 making torque. There must be a system to make 1 to 1 =  torque there is no question if there is.  I have countless geared motors that operate at different torque and the same rpm.

Comment: Ok there are 5. 20 rpm geared motors all the same motor and all different torque. There is a 2 rpm motor with 7 pounds of torque and a 2 rpm with 150 pounds. There is a 1 to 1 that increases torque we just arent using it.  A sun gear with thicker spur gears makes more torque no matter what ratio.  The thicker the gear the more the torque

Comment: The more i check it is proven if its 4 to1 and the gears are made thicker the torque increases just like if its 1 to 1 and the gear thickness increases the torque increases so you need to rewrite history to prevent stupidity